# Remove some code lines in production distribution files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm using `Babel` and `Webpack` to generate `ES5` code from `ES6`. There are some validations that is used to reduce the mistakes i do while coding.

```
class Logger {
    /**
     * @param {LogModel} info
     *  {LogTypes} type
     *  {String} message
     *  {Date} date
     */
    static log(info) {
        if(info instanceof LogModel)
            throw new Error("not a instance of LogModel");

        notify(info);
    }
}
```

In `log` function, I validate whether the argument is a instance of `LogModel` class. This is just to prevent mistakes. I don't want that if condition to be in the production because too many if condition going to slow the application. Is it possible to generate development release with validations and production release without those validations with `Babel` and `Webpack`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It appears the other answers are outdated. With webpack 4, you can set `mode: 'production'` in your webpack config.

In your code, check for development mode like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    if(info instanceof LogModel)
        throw new Error("not a instance of LogModel");
}
```

When webpack creates a bundle with `mode: 'production'`, all the code inside these if clauses, along with the if clauses themselves, will be automatically removed from the bundle.

There is no need to use the define plugin explicitly (it is used by webpack “under the hood”), and it's not necessary to use something like `webpack-unassert-loader` or `webpack-strip-block` mentioned in other answers.

Check out this little demo repo I have made to try this out: https://github.com/pahund/webpack-devprod-experiment

Comment: webpack will not remove the if block from the compiled code

Comment: My bad. For some reason webpack does not override env.NODE_ENV.

Comment: This not work for me. I had to add `declare let process`

Comment: @Rafff which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: What if you dont want to strip all the code in that block. The `webpack-strip-block` seems to give you much more control.

Comment: @Tamb All the code in that block *is* stripped by webpack

Comment: @Patrick Hund, I like that this is built in. Can you alias this rather long condition to something shorter like `window.DEV_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'` and still have this get stripped out: `window.DEV_ENV && assert(true)`

Comment: @DevinGRhode No, it only works reliably if you it like I show in my code example. I tried out your code in my demo repo, it didn't work.

Comment: I believe under the hood webpack uses [ConstPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/internal-plugins/#constplugin) to resolve `if…statements` into simple `true/false`. You can use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) which is internal webpack plugin to achieve this behaviour. That page also contains a very simple example on how to use.

Comment: Is it possible to write an assert function somewhere in my codebase, such that importing it and running `assert(false)` only crashes in development?

Comment: Pretty much, what I want to do is have a "zero-cost" assert function for development and for TypeScript (so instead of using `as` type assertions I can write an assert to verify this)

Answer (score 11):

[webpack-strip-block](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-strip-block) is a good solution. It removes a block of code in your production code when compiling.

```
/* develblock:start */
/* develblock:end */
```

Not limited to `assert`s and no redundant code in prod.

Comment: With webpack 4 this is not necessary, it has built-in support via `mode` config and `process.env.NODE_ENV`

Comment: webpack does not removes dev code even with `mode = production`

Answer (score 9):

A cleaner option will be using [define-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) from webpack.

In config file:

`new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __DEV: JSON.stringify(true)
})`

app.js:

`if(__DEV){
  console.log("logged only in dev env")
}`

value of `__DEV` will be provided by webpack at compile time.

Comment: __DEV appears it will always be true in your example. Shouldn't it be `JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')`?

Comment: If using `eslint` you may also need `"globals": { "__DEV": true }` in your `.eslintrc` file. Otherwise `eslint` may complain: `error  '__DEV' is not defined  no-undef`.

Comment: You can't remove method in a class with this approach. Isn't?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [assert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assert) package to enforce your code, then use [webpack-unassert-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-unassert-loader) or [webpack-strip-assert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-strip-assert) to strip your assertions for production code.

```
var assert = require('assert').ok;

class Logger {
    /**
     * @param {LogModel} info
     *  {LogTypes} type
     *  {String} message
     *  {Date} date
     */
    static log(info) {
        assert(info instanceof LogModel, "Param must be an instance of LogModel");
        notify(info);
    }
}
```

Comment: I adopted this approach because I wanted assertions to be completely stripped from the source code in production. However `webpack-strip-assert` threw an error with Webpack 4. I used `string-replace-webpack-plugin` with the replacement pattern `/\n[ \t]*assert\([^\);]+[\)\s]+[ \t]*[;\n]/g` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I created a [sample project](https://github.com/geri-m/remove-ts-code) to evaluate all the different approaches explain in this thread. My favorite is to use  [string-replace-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin).

Comment: [string-replace-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-webpack-plugin) is a great suggestion but it's no longer maintained and is broken with newer Webpack versions.

Answer (score 2):

There are some great options here, but I think we can do better. If you're trying to completely remove the `Logger.log()` function as well as calls to it like:

```js
Logger.log('Remove me');
```

**...then [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader) can do what we need!**

Install `string-replace-loader`:

```sh
npm install --save-dev string-replace-loader
```

Then, in your Webpack config:

```js
...
    module: {
        rules: [
            //Replace strings
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'string-replace-loader',
                options: {
                    multiple: [
                        //Remove calls to Logger.log()
                        {
                            search: /Logger\.log\s*\(.*?\);?\s*?\n/g,
                            replace: '\n'
                        },
                        //Remove the actual Logger.log() function. This regex may need tweaking depending on your actual code for `log()`.
                        {
                            search: /static\s*log\s*\([^}]*}/gs,
                            replace: ''
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
...
```

No need to add extra meaningless code to the actual source code. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62243207/114558) for pointing me in the right direction (albeit to an outdated plugin).

Comment: I have tried several options, but this solution worked best, because it keeps the code clean. The only limitation that I found is that the `Logger.log(...)`  calls must not contain a line break.