# Typescript - Removing some lines of code from production

Tags: typescript, development-environment, environment, production-environment

I'm trying to remove some code that should only appear in development mode, from production.
I've done this many times before using Webpack, as explained here

[Remove some code lines in production distribution files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776264/remove-some-code-lines-in-production-distribution-files)

This is my first time trying to do the same with typescript - Can the same be achieved?
I'm using Typescript as my compiler (no webpack or rollup), and I'm creating an ESM bundle with it.

Do I need another tool to strip dead code?

For reference this is what I'm trying to remove from my production build

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
   console.log('Just a test');
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, this is not the job for typescript compiler, so you probably need some other tool to do that.

Comment: Thanks, so something like rollup over the output of typescript?

Comment: Yep, that sounds good to me. Unless you can tell rollup to compile TS, that would be better