# cleanup development code from prodection buid

Tags: typescript, webpack, optimization, nestjs, webpack-production

I use NestJS application in nx project

i use this approach

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Code will only appear in production build.
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  // Code will be removed from production build.
  console.log("Looks like you're a developer.");
}
```

i used also any other approach even use chatgpt

i need alll the code in the none prodection block code to be deleted from the prodection code.

this is very important becuse in the none production code i lazy import hard coded mock in the code, and this data is very sensitive and increase the server size which cost as allots off money.

please help me find a sulotion to spear unwanted code base on procces.env.NODE_ENV mode approach.

any third party package or advance Typescript configuration is an option

the app code

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SomeRandomService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  randomRequest(body: any): Promise<any> {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      return firstValueFrom(
        this.httpService.post(`someRandomUrl`, body, {
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
          },
        })
      );
    } else {
      return import('some-random-path-to-mock.mock');
    }
  }
}
```

please let me know if any further information is needed like `project.json` or `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62246731/typescript-removing-some-lines-of-code-from-production), it is not possible with TypeScript. Though I do not have experience with it, using [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) with [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-strip-code) should do what you want.