# Remove Code blocks based on Environment Nx Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-4, nrwl-nx

I'm really interested in inserting or removing code blocks in my Angular App based on the environment. Specifically removing certain import declarations and related code that should not be used for Production keeping the bundle light, while getting the benefit of extra code in the dev environment. I know webpack can handle code trasformations, so I was wondering if there was any solution that can remove code blocks based on special syntax?

e.g.

```
// Special Import handled by Webpack
import { logger } from '@loggerzMaximus/core' in 'development'; // 1GB!!

export class AppComponent {

    ngOnInit() {

        // Should be stripped by webpack + import if env is not development
        logger.log('LoggerzMaximus works for dev!');

    }
  
}
```

From this answer I've seen that webpack 4 can automatically handle an if statement for `node`

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062307/3859456
- Another Post: https://newbedev.com/remove-some-code-lines-in-production-distribution-files.

--

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    if(info instanceof LogModel)
        throw new Error("not a instance of LogModel");
}
```

Does anyone know a way to strip code based on the environment?

Answer (score 0):

Angular makes use of tree shaking your builds with the Ivy compiler while using the `--prod` flag so you can use the `environment.ts` to check your environment and then any code that isn't used while it is running in production mode will be left out of your bundles by the Angular compilation.

NX actually makes additional optimizations above and beyond this simple explanation as well.

Here is a brief introduction to tree shaking to help clarify: [Angular tree shaking in-depth](https://indepth.dev/posts/1258/a-gentle-introduction-into-tree-shaking-in-angular-ivy)