# ReactJS to have code only available in dev envrionment

Tags: reactjs

I have a ContextProvider that does things a little different in production than in development. The background is that the app is supposed to get embedded in a CMS and the form is provided by the CMS. However I develop it standalone because the CMS is also still in development by someone else, therefore I created my own form and API.

I have in dev environment two useEffect hooks that take in data from my mockup API

```
if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {

  useEffect(()=>{
    setWidth(parseInt(props.width));
  }, [props.width]);
  //...
}
```

`props.width` (as an example) gets assigned to the ContextProvider-component only in development, it's not supposed to be available in production.

However I can not have useEffect in a condition. How would I prevent development-functionality being compiled in the production build? Is it good practice to have the whole ContextProvider in a condition one version with the development functionality and in the else branch again but without development functionality? This would however mean I have some code twice...

PS: Please note that I did not want to have the useEffect appear in production. So having the condition inside the useEffect is not a solution, this way I would have an useEffect in production that is never getting used as props.width doesn't even exist in this case.

Comment: You could put the if statement inside the ‘useEffect’.

Comment: Yes I know but that would make the useEffect getting compiled into production, which I did not want.

Comment: Yes but it would do nothing which is probably fine but if you really want to remove the useEffect in your production code, you could creat a component which returns null and has this effect inside and renders it only in development mode. Render the component with the hook conditionally instead of the hook itself, which you cannot.

Comment: So there is no equivalent to #ifdef of c compilers, that only compile code that's relevant? Edit: I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062307/12848667 webpack 4 removes unused code.

Comment: Not exactly, you cannot use hooks conditionally no matter what (except the new `use` hook). As I said I think the best you can do is to use `process.env.NODE_ENV`. Something like `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? <NonProductionComponent /> : null`. The `NonProductionComponent` won't be part of your production bundle. See [react-query-devtools](https://github.com/TanStack/query/blob/main/packages/react-query-devtools/src/index.ts). The devtools will not appear in the production bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Hooks cannot be called conditionally, so just move condition inside `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    setWidth(parseInt(props.width));
  }
}, [props.width]);
```

Comment: No, as said I did not want the useEffect to appear in production. It is useless code there that never will get called.

Comment: @user6329530 I don't understand what's the difference - running empty useEffect is practically free from performance viewpoint and space wise in both cases (if outside, if inside) same amount of code is sent to client. Even if you put if around useEffect it will still be compiled to production bundle. Perhaps if you make two almost identical components, one with useEffect and one without and depend on treeshaking to only import correct one?

Comment: Yes I wanted it not to be compiled in the production code. useEffect gets compiled into some javascript code and that is useless space that's wasted.

Answer (score 1):

React rules say:
**Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.**

But this is not exactly true. The real rule is:

**The amount of hook calls should be same inside the component on each render after the component mount.**

So, if you ensure that the condition you use is always false or always true after the component mount, you can put the hooks inside condition.

checking `process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"`is always true or always false after you start your app, you can not change it during runtime via .env (you have to restart the app in order for the changes to be applied) and this is a valid condition.

You have to disable eslint `rule of hooks` for that use

Comment: Is it true that in the case of process.env.NODE_ENV being production the whole condition does not get compiled into the code?

Comment: I am not sure about this, it is something related to the module bundler you use. You can research about tree-shaking for your bundler. But even if it goes to production, it does not execute the useEffect, but only that "if condition" and it returns false

Comment: However it would take up space. I am thinking like a c compiler who would run optimization that removes unused code during compile time (think #ifdef macros).

Comment: That is true. I think Webpack removes the dead code from the build. As I said, I'm not sure. I do not know what module bundler you use. Better go and test it.

Comment: I will test it, thanks. I am running create-react-app with webpack. Edit: just found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776264/remove-some-code-lines-in-production-distribution-files

Comment: Did you test it? Was it successful?

Comment: Hello, no, sorry it does not seem to be possible. The only way I could think of was create a duplicate "dev stage" component and have that if condition in the return block of the parent component. But that is not practicable as it would mean that I have duplicate code that does almost the same.